# How can i export an object inside a server component function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, prisma, next.js13

im trying to make a simple login form with Next13 and prisma, i made a function that checks wether if the username and password inputted in the form is inside the database using prisma.findfirst function

i made it into this object called 'Ldata', the FormData comes from a clientcomponent form witch has the 'action ={Logged}' attribute

i want the object to be exported or returned as an object that can be imported/used in other pages. How?

```
export async function Logged(fdata: FormData) {
  const datnama = fdata.get("Username") ?.toString()
  const datpassword = Number(fdata.get("password"))
  let passwordcorrect:boolean = false;
  const Ldata = await prisma.user.findFirst({
    where: {
      nama: datnama,
      NISN: datpassword
    },
    select: {
      nama: true,
      NISN:true
    }
  })
  if (Ldata) {
    passwordcorrect = true;
    console.log("yep")
  } else {
    passwordcorrect = false
    console.log("nop")
  }
  (passwordcorrect) ? redirect('/') : redirect('/Login/Loginerror');
}
```

i tried calling the 'Logged' function to get the object but it needed the 'fdata' argument to be filled, which is a formdata that i cant fill :/